# Visual Studio .NET MVC deploy to Google Cloud into specific Site on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Where can I find information to deploy a web project (.NET MVC) to a specific IIS Site on the Cloud Server?

I can't seem to find any information on how to do that. The idea is to host multiple websites on the server, but also use the `Publish to Google Cloud...` feature while selecting what `Site` to publish to on `IIS`.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Tools for Visual Studio currently supports publishing only to the default application on an IIS on a GCE VM.
I've created a [feature request](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-visualstudio/issues/944) on github so you can track progress there.